# Add text and rename multiple files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

Okay,
I have a lot of subfolders. Each subfolder contains some files. In each subfolder I want to add som text in the end of one file with the extension "tbn". The file name is not the same in each folder. Then I also want to change/rename the extension to jpg. See my example below

rename "myfile.tbn" to "myfile-poster.jpg"

I would like to do this from the command promt or from a batch file.

Have googled some of this. I would say my problem is to add the text in the end of the file "-poster" when the orginal filename varies.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. See my answer please.

Comment: **You should have clarifed your directory structure**. If you have a parent directory containing one level of subdirectories, then in a Command Prompt window, with the current directory as the parent for those subdirectories: ```For /D %G In (*) Do @For %H In ("%G\*.tbn") Do @If /I "%~xH" == ".tbn" Ren "%H" "%~nH-poster.jpg"```. If you have a parent directory containing multiple levels of subdirectories, then in a Command Prompt window, with the current directory as the parent for that subdirectory structure: ```For /R %G In (*.tbn) Do @If /I "%~xG" == ".tbn" Ren "%G" "%~nG-poster.jpg"```.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a file with an unknown name with a plain `for` loop (see `for /?` for details).
`/R` makes it recursive (searching through subfolders too)
the `%%~n` modifier returns the base filename only (no extension)

```
for /R %%A  in (*.tbn) do ECHO ren "%%A" "%%~nA-poster.jpg"
```

Remove the `ECHO` after verifying it does what you want to actually enable the `ren` command.